# adding pages dynamically in libharu C

Tags: c, pdf-generation, libharu

I'm generating a pdf report the problem is that i don't know how many pages the report will be it will vary a lot. I need to create a the pages dynamically as they are need it, I try this but it doesn't work.

```
//page counter
int page_num=1;

HPDF_Doc  pdf;
HPDF_Page *page;
char fname[256];
HPDF_Destination dst;
//This works for the first page 
page = malloc(sizeof(*page));
if (page==NULL) {
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
} else {
    printf("allocation successful\n");
}
```

and i'm able to write to the pdf file normally, but when i try to create another page
i get a segmentation fault. I try like this.

```
page_num ++;
HPDF_Page *temp;
*temp = realloc(page, (page_num+2) * sizeof(page));
if ( temp != NULL ) //realloc was successful
{
page = temp;
page[page_num] = HPDF_AddPage (pdf); //** This line makes it crash **//

printf("Success Reallocating into page\n");
}
else //there was an error
{  printf("Error reallocating into page\n"); }
```

I'm trying to do it like this because i need to go back to a specific page and insert a footer with the page number example "page 1 of 50" if there is a different way to accomplish this let me know. Also there is an example in their website with multiple pages, but this is set at the beginning with a set number of pages that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

*temp = realloc(page, (page_num+2) * sizeof(page))  error on this statement. The page is an address point, and sizeof(page) is 8

Comment: *temp = realloc(page, (page_num+2) * sizeof(*page)); or *temp = realloc(page, (page_num+2) * sizeof(HPDF_Page));

Answer (score 0):

Look at [type definition HPDF_Page](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/blob/master/include/hpdf.h).
`HPDF_Page p;`
p is pointer
`HPDF_Page *p;`
*p is now double pointer

Malloc memory allocation:

```
HPDF_Page *page; //this is double pointer!!!!

page = malloc(number_of_pages * sizeof(HPDF_Page*)); // memory allocation for array of pointers
if(page) 
{
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_pages; i++)
    {
        page[i] = malloc(sizeof(HPDF_Page)); // allocation for each page pointer
        page[i] = HPDF_AddPage (pdf);
    }
}
```

Realloc memory allocation:

```
number_of_pages++;
page = realloc(page, number_of_pages * sizeof(HPDF_Page*)); 

if(page) 
{
        page[number_of_pages-1] = malloc(sizeof(HPDF_Page));
        page[number_of_pages-1] = HPDF_AddPage (pdf);
}
```

**Malloc will work. But the realloc will not work and program will fail!!! I am not sure why. The working method is using of linked list:**

```
struct my_ch
{
    struct my_ch *n;
    struct my_ch *p;
    HPDF_Page page;
    int page_number;
}*f_item = NULL, *l_item = NULL;

void add_item()
{
    struct my_ch *pom;
    pom = f_item;

    if(pom)
    {
        struct my_ch *prev;

        while(pom->n)
        {
             pom = pom->n;
        }

        prev = pom;
        pom->n = malloc(sizeof(struct my_ch));
        pom = pom->n;
        pom->p = prev;
        pom->n = NULL;
        pom->page = malloc(sizeof(HPDF_Page));
        pom->page_number = pom->prev->page_number + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        pom = malloc(sizeof(struct my_ch));
        pom->p = NULL;
        pom->n = NULL;
        pom->page = malloc(sizeof(HPDF_Page));
        pom->page_number = 1;
    }

    l_item = pom;
}

void add_my_new_page()
{
    add_item();
    l_item->page = HPDF_AddPage(pdf);
    //paste some nice graphic, text...
}

bool modify_page(int number_of_page)
{
    struct my_ch *p;
    p = f_item;

    while(p)
    {
        if(p->page_number == number_of_page)
        {
            // let`s do some modifycation on p->page
            HPDF_Page_Rectangle( p->page, ..., ...);
            HPDF_Page_Stroke(p->page);

            return true;
        }

        p = p->n;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I use this code in my program and it works nicely.